# Reducing time complexity of bilinear interpolation

Tags: java, android, algorithm, opencv, time-complexity

I use bilinear interpolation in my android application. It runs perfectly, but takes a lot of time to get the result.

I test it when xi = 259,920, and yi also = 259,920. The time to response was: Galaxy Note 4 takes 3 sec, 
                          and HTC One M8 takes about 8 sec !. So what I can change or use to reduce the time?!

The code I use for bilinear interpolation:

```
public static double[] BiInterp(Mat z, ArrayList < Double > xi, ArrayList < Double > yi) {
    // Declare matrix indeces
    int xi_i, yi_i;
    // Initialize output vector
    double zi[] = new double[xi.size()];
    double s00, s01, s10, s11;
    for (int i = 0; i < xi.size(); i++) { // Note: xi.length = yi.length !
        xi_i = xi.get(i).intValue(); // X index without round
        yi_i = yi.get(i).intValue(); // Y index without round
        if (xi_i < z.rows() - 1 && yi_i < z.cols() - 1 && xi_i >= 0 && yi_i >= 0) {
            // Four neighbors of sample pixel
                s00 = z.get(xi_i,yi_i)[0]; s01 = z.get(xi_i,yi_i + 1)[0];
                s10 = z.get(xi_i + 1,yi_i)[0];s11 = z.get(xi_i + 1,yi_i + 1)[0];

            int neighbor_no = 4; // As bilinear interpolation take 4 neighbors
            double A[][] = new double[neighbor_no][neighbor_no];

            A[0][0]=xi_i; A[0][1]=yi_i; A[0][2]=xi_i*yi_i; A[0][3]=1;
            A[1][0]=xi_i; A[1][1]=yi_i+1; A[1][2]=xi_i*(yi_i+1); A[1][3]=1;
            A[2][0]=xi_i+1; A[2][1]=yi_i; A[2][2]=(xi_i+1)*yi_i; A[2][3]=1;
            A[3][0]=xi_i+1; A[3][1]=yi_i+1; A[3][2]=(xi_i+1)*(yi_i+1); A[3][3]=1;

            GaussianElimination solveE = new GaussianElimination();
            double b[] = {s00,s01,s10,s11};
            double x[] = solveE.solve(A, b);
            zi[i] = xi.get(i)*x[0] + yi.get(i)*x[1] + xi.get(i)*yi.get(i)*x[2] + x[3];
        }
    }
    return zi;
}
```

and I use Gaussian elimination to solve the equation of 4 unknown

```
private static final double EPSILON = 1e-10;

// Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting
public static double[] solve(double[][] A, double[] b) {
    int N = b.length;

    for (int p = 0; p < N; p++) {

        // find pivot row and swap
        int max = p;
        for (int i = p + 1; i < N; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(A[i][p]) > Math.abs(A[max][p])) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        double[] temp = A[p];
        A[p] = A[max];
        A[max] = temp;
        double t = b[p];
        b[p] = b[max];
        b[max] = t;

        // singular or nearly singular
        if (Math.abs(A[p][p]) <= EPSILON) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Matrix is singular or nearly singular");
        }

        // pivot within A and b
        for (int i = p + 1; i < N; i++) {
            double alpha = A[i][p] / A[p][p];
            b[i] -= alpha * b[p];
            for (int j = p; j < N; j++) {
                A[i][j] -= alpha * A[p][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // back substitution
    double[] x = new double[N];
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            sum += A[i][j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = (b[i] - sum) / A[i][i];
    }
    return x;
}
```

As you see in the bilinear code, I take the pixels intensities immediately from the Mat object. However, when I used matrix it takes much less time, such as with note 4 takes 1 sec.

But to convert from Mat image to matrix takes 4 sec. So I preferred to use Mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more simple bilinear interpolation algorithm:

- Find the fractional part of yi and use it to interpolate between s00 and s01 to find s0, and between s10 and s11 to find s1
- Find the fractional part of xi and use it to interpolate between s0 and s1 to find zi

Basically you are decomposing it into three simple linear interpolations. You can visualize it as an H shape. First you interpolate down the left and right posts of the H to get values part way down each. Then you interpolate along the cross-beam to get the final value in the middle.

The code would be something like this:

```
    xi_i = xi.get(i).intValue(); // X index without round
    yi_i = yi.get(i).intValue(); // Y index without round
    if (xi_i < z.rows() - 1 && yi_i < z.cols() - 1 && xi_i >= 0 && yi_i >= 0) {
        // Four neighbors of sample pixel
        s00 = z.get(xi_i,yi_i)[0]; s01 = z.get(xi_i,yi_i + 1)[0];
        s10 = z.get(xi_i + 1,yi_i)[0];s11 = z.get(xi_i + 1,yi_i + 1)[0];

        // find fractional part of yi:
        double yi_frac = yi.get(i) - (double)yi_i;

        // interpolate between s00 and s01 to find s0:
        double s0 = s00 + ((s01 - s00) * yi_frac);
        // interpolate between s10 and s11 to find s1:
        double s1 = s10 + ((s11 - s10) * yi_frac);

        // find fractional part of xi:
        double xi_frac = xi.get(i) - (double)xi_i;

        // interpolate between s0 and s1 to find zi:
        zi[i] =  s0 + ((s1 - s0) * xi_frac);
    }
```

You could also speed the whole thing up (at the expense of accuracy) by using fixed point integers instead of doubles.

Comment: Thanks, your modification helps me a lot. It reduced the time around half, was 2902 ms on Note 4, and now 1920 ms. I also tried the other solution you suggest and gave me 1844 ms, but I don't prefer to use it. Is there another thing I can do to speed up the response time more?

Comment: I simplified the formula to hopefully give a small speed up. How many times do you call this function? Try allocating zi outside the function once only and pass it in, memory allocations can be slow.

Comment: I call it only once, but the huge input vectors xi and yi make bad response time. Thanks again, I'll keep your solution for now.

Comment: @Sheikhah Maasher  Are your input vectors xi and yi ordered by some way?